# How connect two emulator to lan network android?

Tags: android-layout, android-networking

How  connect two emulator to lan network android? I would like to send info from one emulator to second using wifi and socket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/).  It works great in VirtualBox and it even has a [tutorial](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/virtualboxhowto).

Just set the VM's up on their own network or even bridge them to the host machine's network.  Works like a champ!!!